# Getting client IP address in websocket library

Tags: haskell, websocket, haskell-snap-framework

I am using `Network.WebSocket` library. I tried `WS.requestHeaders . WS.pendingRequest` on `PendingConnection` to get the connection request information. However, it seems it doesn't have client IP information, only the server IP information in `Host` key. An example output below:

```
[("Upgrade","websocket"),("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions","permessage-deflate; 
client_max_window_bits"),("Sec-WebSocket-Key","<taken out for SO post>"),
("Connection","Upgrade"),("Sec-WebSocket-Version","13"),("Host","localhost:8080")]
```

What will be a good way to get the "Client IP" information when running `Network.Websocket` (I am running it within `Snap` monad using `runWebSocketsSnap`). I will like to log it in case of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runWebSocketsSnap` is just a regular `Snap` application, so you can use [`rqRemoteAddr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.7.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:rqRemoteAddr) to get remote IP address:

```
do
  addr <- getsRequest rqRemoteAddr
  runWebSocketsSnap $ \pending -> ...
```